# Closing a process

Tags: php

I have the following script that generates images. The problem is that the process running the script doesn't close. It just stays open and I eventually get notifications from CSF that the process time exceeded a certain time limit. What change can I make to the code to fix this?

```
<?php
$rgb = $_GET["color"];
$rgb = intval("0x" . $rgb, 16);
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(250,250);
imagefill($img,1,1,$rgb);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($img, NULL, 100);
imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

Comment: what is the "process running the script" ?

Comment: It's somebody going to my website. The notification I get is:

Time:         Mon Feb  6 11:59:50 2017 -0500
Account:      xxx
Resource:     Process Time
Exceeded:     9457 > 1000 (seconds)
Executable:   /usr/bin/php
Command Line: /usr/bin/php
PID:          1301 (Parent PID:1301)
Killed:       No

When I check the PID it's the above php file.